# Prove that $\,\lambda^*(Α)+\lambda^*(Β)= \lambda^*(A\cup B)\,$ if $\,A\subseteq G\,$ and $\,G\cap B=\emptyset\,.$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

What could be a rigorous proof that $λ^{*}(Α) + λ^{*}(Β) = λ^{*}(A\cup B)$ ?

We know that $A\subseteq G$ and $G\cap B = \emptyset$, and $\,λ^*$ the Lebesgue outer measure.
Suppose all sets involved are measurable and subsets of $\,\mathbb R$.

One proof might be to use the definition of the measure, and the fact that $A\cup B=(a,b)\cup(c,d)$ where $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ the smallest possible sets in $\mathbb R$ containing $A$ and $B$ respectively.

But I don’t know if the professor would accept that or if there is a more rigorous way to prove this equality (e.g., one based on some property of the Lebesgue measure)

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Hint : start by writing $\lambda^*(A\cup B) = \lambda^*\big((A\cup B)\cap G\big) + \lambda^*\big((A\cup B)\cap G^c\big)  $ and use your assumptions

Comment: Are you sure that *all* sets involved are assumed measurable? If so, $G$ is useless (its existence is equivalent to $A\cap B=\varnothing$) and the result is obvious ($\lambda^*=\lambda$ on these sets).

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes, that seems to be just fine! Thanks everyone for your help